# xlwings unable to create new workbook on macos

Tags: python, excel, macos, xlwings

I tried a simple workbook creation on macos 12.01:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book()
```

Excel launched but didn't create the workbook, instead threw an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/rf/tstbf33n7cz0l2b92l8149980000gn/T/ipykernel_17484/3332672052.py in <module>
      1 import xlwings as xw
----> 2 wb = xw.Book()

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/main.py in __init__(self, fullname, update_links, read_only, format, password, write_res_password, ignore_read_only_recommended, origin, delimiter, editable, notify, converter, add_to_mru, local, corrupt_load, impl)
    693                 else:
    694                     app = App()
--> 695                     impl = app.books[0].impl
    696 
    697         self.impl = impl

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/main.py in __getitem__(self, key)
     72             l = len(self)
     73             if key >= l:
---> 74                 raise IndexError("Index %s out of range (%s elements)" % (key, l))
     75             if key < 0:
     76                 if key < -l:

IndexError: Index 0 out of range (0 elements)
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: No issues running this on my side, but I'm not using Anaconda, just plain XLWings. Upon calling the workbook the first time, I got prompted for permissions to listen to System events, so you might be missing that.

Comment: I tried multiple times. Error is very reproducible. It doesn't prompt me for any permissions either. This seems a rather serious issue, basically rendering automations useless.

Comment: Based on the line numbering looks like the xlwings is not the latest release. Are you able to update to the latest 0.26.x and try with that?

Comment: updated all, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem.

And I found that this program can be successfully executed with a excel window open.

Finally I tried to create a book successfully without any excel window open by using the follwing statement instead:

```
import xlwings as xw
book_arr=xw.App().books
wb =book_arr.add()
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

Comment: This didn't work for me either. Now it asks for permissions. After granting it, it fails. It's remarkable that such basic operation will fail. This casts doubt on the whole package. I hope alternative packages will be created with better quality control. Hate excel though.